# Using Service to pass data between components angular2

Tags: angular

I am passing data between two components using service

UserComponent

```
onSubmit(username:string){
    this.dataService.push(this.user);
    this.navigate();
}

navigate(){
    this.router.navigate(['question']);
}
```

Question Component

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '.././services/data.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'question',
  templateUrl: 'question.component.html',
})
export class QuestionComponent {
name : string;
constructor(private dataService: DataService, private renderer: Renderer) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Here");
    this.dataService.pushData.subscribe((data:any) => this.name = data);
  }
```

Service

```
import { Injectable,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{
    pushData = new EventEmitter<string>();

    push(value:string){
        console.log("In Service");
        this.pushData.emit(value);
    }
}
```

}

But i am able able to get the data in the question component and no error in console

Comment: Please provide more code. Where do you provide the service. What is the exact class declaration (name and decorator). Currently it's entirely unclear where is what happening.

Comment: Where do you provide the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have the `UserComponent` loaded and you push some data to the service.
2. The service fires an event for those interested in the data push
3. You navigate and load the `QuestionComponent`
4. The `QuestionComponent` then subscribes to the service event (*too late*)

Long story short: Step 2 happened before step 4 so step 4s event handler for pushed data will never fire, it started listening too late (after the event was called).

---

### Edit

What you are probably looking for (*I realize in hindsight*) is to pass parameters to your component during navigation, ie. parameters in the route. If that is all you need a service is not necessary, you can pass them using the routing types and read them back in your component.

See the documentation on [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters)

**UserComponent**

```
navigate(){
    this.router.navigate(['question', {user: this.user}]);
}
```

**QuestionComponent**

```
import { ActivatedRoute  } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const user = this.route.snapshot.params['user'];
}
```

Comment: why are we getting the array back in the Question Component this.data, do i need to create an additional array

Comment: @INFOSYS - I am not following your questions. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: in the question component this line 
this.data = this.dataService.data.slice(0); // initial load of already present values, slice makes a copy of the array



,we are basically storing it in service and retriving the values , how to work with just the event emitter. i donot want to use a local storage again here

Comment: @INFOSYS - then remove slice and let the service track the data. Either way you need to read the already loaded data in during `ngOnInit` because the question component was possibly (*actually definitely in this case*) not yet active when data was loaded by other components.

Comment: so this means that we need to have local storage to access data passed by the user component, this way we need not have an event emitter as the value passed by the user component will given by the user , we can just use a local storage

Comment: @INFOSYS - The only other way around this is if you wanted to push the value for navigation. In that case you can provide the value to the route with the `navigate` command and read that value back in your question component. Maybe this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes i didnot want to store that value i just want the user entered value to be displayed as a hello user value in the question component, how do we acheive that ?

Comment: @INFOSYS - If this worked for you please consider accepting it as the answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235))